# Trying to get data of a column from MySQL in date format

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table with name `customer` and in this, i have a column with name `callback_date`. It is a `varchar` field. And I want to get its data as DATE.

Here is how I make my query.

```
SELECT callback_date AS calld
FROM customer
WHERE callback_date<>''
  AND STR_TO_DATE('calld', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Why my data is not returning in date format of this particular column? Any specific query I need to run?

Comment: change this **STR_TO_DATE('calld', '%d/%m/%Y')** to **STR_TO_DATE(callback_date, '%d/%m/%Y')**

Comment: You can't use column alias in where statement [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: Thank you Pathik it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

don't know what exactly you want but maybe this is what I understand, query should be:

```
SELECT temp.*
FROM
  (SELECT callback_date AS calld,
          DATE_FORMAT(callback_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dt
   FROM customer
   WHERE callback_date <> '') AS temp
WHERE temp.dt = '18/03/2016'
```